# Django Haystack - How to order by timestamp?

Tags: django-haystack

I'm new to Django and Haystack... I need to know how can I order my search results by date/timestamp, most recent first.

Here is my model.py:

```
class adsText(models.Model):
    hash          = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    title         = models.TextField()
    description   = models.TextField()
    country       = models.TextField()
    zone          = models.TextField()
    location      = models.TextField()
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'ads_text'
        managed = False

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

My search_indexes.py:

```
class adsTextIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text            = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title           = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    description     = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')
    zone            = indexes.CharField(model_attr='zone')
    location        = indexes.CharField(model_attr='location')
    date_inserted   = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_inserted')

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return adsText.objects.order_by('-date_inserted')
        #return adsText.objects.filter(date_inserted__lte=datetime.datetime.now())

site.register(adsText, adsTextIndex)
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
)
```

I have tested to change to this line of code in search_indexes.py but it not working as expected:

```
return adsText.objects.order_by('-date_inserted')
```

I have read that the way to go is to use something like this in the urls.py:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('-date_inserted')
```

My doubt is how can I add this code to the "urlpatterns" of urls.py, any clue on how to achieve this?

Best Regards,

Comment: You can add order on meta def of model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering

Comment: Hi danihp. Thanks for the reply. But it does not work.

Comment: Have you try: ordering = ['-date_inserted'] on Meta Class and don't work? It is bizarre. Perphaps haystack bypass ordering meta model.

Comment: Hi danihp. yes I have tried. I'm using Solr with Haystack. I think that Haystack does not search the model, search only the Solr index in this case.

Comment: Here an example how to change queryset in URL: http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/views_and_forms.html (views section)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html#views

Specifically, you probably want your urlconf to look like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import SearchView

sqs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('-date_inserted')

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^search/$', SearchView(
        searchqueryset=sqs,
    )),
)
```

Comment: What does order_by return? When I try to do a for loop in the template, I get "object of type 'SearchResult' has no len()". Doesn't it return a SearchQuerySet that can be looped over? I'm confused over this one.

Comment: It returns a SearchQuerySet, which is an iterable of SearchResult objects. Sounds like you're trying to loop over a single SearchResult?

Comment: I had to use filter for it to work, this is within my views.py file so it must be different. I did MySearchQuerySet.filter().order_by('-date_start'). This is suppose to be identical to the "latest" function of Haystack, but I can't seem to loop over what latest function returns, facing some weird difficulties. Thanks for the response though.